# Can insert in an fstream, but not in an iostream

Tags: c++, stl, iostream, fstream

Trying to insert a string in the middle of a file, starting from its end.

The following code works with an fstream, but not with an iostream (in this case the output string is equal to the input one):

```
    // File contents: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstxyz"; "uvw" missing

    // 1 - OK
    //fstream  iofs(fPath, ios_base::in | ios_base::out);

    // 2 - Same output
    filebuf   fileBuffer;
    iostream  iofs(&fileBuffer);    // generic output stream
    fileBuffer.open(fPath.c_str(), ios_base::in | ios_base::out | ofstream::app);
    iofs.rdbuf(&fileBuffer);

    iofs.seekg(0, ios_base::end);
    iofs.seekp(0, ios_base::end);

    for(int i = 1; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        iofs.seekg(-i, std::ios_base::end);

        char c = char(iofs.peek());

        if(c == 't') {
            iofs.seekp(-i + 1, std::ios_base::end);
            iofs << "uvw";      // add missing token
            iofs << "xyz";      // append pre-existing token
            break;
        }
    }
```

Output:
Case 1: Begin  = abcdefghijklmnopqrstxyz; Result = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Case 2: Begin  = abcdefghijklmnopqrstxyz; Result = abcdefghijklmnopqrstxyz

Am I doing something wrong, or I simply cannot do an insert in a iostream?

Comment: Are you checking the content of the stream at the end or of the file? Just guessing here but maybe the fstream does an implicit flush on destruction or some file synchronization and the iostream not. You can try a flush at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic iostream is not seekable - think keyboard or printer.

You don't check the result of the `seekp` operation. It probably fails and sets the stream into an error state. Any further output attempts will then do nothing.